# Bottom bracket replacement bearing

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have been looking for a press-fit bottom bracket replacement bearing for a Giant Fastroad SLR1 (2016 model).

The markings on it identify it as an FSA 19mm diameter, that is the spindle is 19 mm I think.

I took it to my LBS, they did a botch job with some replacement bearings, not the full unit, which I had to re-adjust myself as they tightened it far too tight.

Can anyone recommend where I could get some replacements from please?

[image]

Comment: Is this the bike:  https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/fastroad-slr-1-2016 ?

Comment: Yes that is the bike.

Comment: It's probably best if you post pictures of the bottom bracket and bearings.  The proper replacement depends on the exact specifics of the crankset such as the spindle length, what's already there (BB30 to external BSA adapter, for example) and exact bottom bracket shell - I'm guessing it's BB30 (42 mm press fit, 68 mm wide), but it might be something different.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the new bearings? Why do you need new ones? Depending on the press fit type, just the bearing units may be replaced. Also, what was far too tight? The bearing preload?

Answer (score 2):

Your bike has an FSA Omega crank that does in fact have a 19mm spindle. All press fit BB types either use a 24 or 30mm spindle, so you must have a special BB unit. I'm guessing that it's an [FSA 19mm to BB86](https://shop.fullspeedahead.com/en/type/bottom-brackets-spares/megaexo-and-19omm-spindle-cranks-to-press-fit-bb86-frame).

You should confirm that you have a BB86 frame, you can do that by measuring the width of the BB shell, it should be about 86mm.